# How can I add two form values together (separated by a /) to make a single variable with both items?

Tags: php

I have a form that has two values, month and year.

```
 <option value="01">Jan</option> 
 <option value="19">2019</option>
```

I have a php line that sets the form value (on submit) to a variable in php:

```
$ExpYear = $_POST['ExpMon'+"/"+'ExpYear'];
```

However this doesn't seem to work.

How can I make the variable $ExpYear = 01/19 ?

Thanks!

Comment: use . for concatenation not +

Comment: `$ExpYear = $_POST['ExpMon'] . "/" . $_POST['ExpYear'];`

Comment: So it would be: $ExpYear = $_POST['ExpMon'."/".'ExpYear'];
?

Comment: _However this doesn't seem to work._ Cause you were doing it in wrong way

Comment: Those `options` must be from different drop-down lists and each with a different `name`. After that you'll be able to use @Tanuel Mategi solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
$ExpYear = $_POST['ExpMon'] . "/". $_POST['ExpYear'];
```

not

```
$ExpYear = $_POST['ExpMon'+"/"+'ExpYear'];
```

provided that they are from two select lists. One with name `ExpMon` and other with `ExpYear`

Comment: Thanks! I'll award this best answer in 6 mins